# Quit / open an app whenever audio output is changed on mac

Tags: applescript, audio, bluetooth, headphones, automation

I'm using [Boom](https://www.globaldelight.com/boom/) as an equalizer and a File Audio Boosting on my MBP when using built-in speakers. But when using a home device (with an amplifier connected by jack to the MBP) or a headphone (bluetooth or jack) I prefer to disconnect *Boom*.

So far I have made an automator script that connect/disconnect bluetooth and quit/launch *Boom*.

Is there a way to upgrade my current script to be triggered with plugging/unplugging of jack or connecting/disconnecting with bluetooth device (not only when activating/disactivating bluetooth)?

Note : I'm aware of [Breakaway](https://github.com/steakknife/breakaway) that Automatically disable speakers when headphones are removed (but only by manually connect/disconnect the jack), but something that quit/launch a specific app will suit me better.

For the curious, here my current script using [Blueutil](https://github.com/toy/blueutil) :

```
set BT to do shell script "/usr/local/bin/blueutil -p"

if BT is equal to "0" then
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/blueutil -p 1"
    tell application "Boom 2" to quit
else
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/blueutil -p 0"
    tell application "Boom 2" to activate
end if
```

Comment: You would probably need a third-party app like _Keyboard Maestro_ that can trigger scripts (amongst other things) in response to different events occurring on your system. It's a paid app, but the trial period will let you determine whether it suits your needs. AppleScript can do the bits you're already having it do, but it can't listen for Bluetooth events.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! I will try it when I can.. But are you insinuating that applescript cannot automatically run something with a trigger (like unplugging headphone) ?

Comment: Have a look at [EventScripts](https://www.mousedown.net/software/EventScripts.html) It's [$3.99 at the US App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/eventscripts/id525319418?mt=12), but a free demo is downloadable from the developers website. Note: I am not affiliated with the developer of EventScripts, just a satisfied user of the product.

Comment: A little more than insinuating, but yes. With the exception of _Folder Actions_, AppleScript can't/doesn't monitor low-level system events, so cannot be used to create triggers. Some scriptable apps provide triggers for higher-level in-app events that AppleScript can use, eg. _BBEdit_ application/document listeners. But for a sustainable, usable solution, you want the means to listen for messages the system broadcasts whenever something happens. What you don't want is an AppleScript repeat loop badgering the system with _"are we there yet?"_.

Comment: Actually, any form of polling is not good, but it's the only thing AppleScript can do. The exception to this is by way of AppleScriptObjC, which one could borrow the means to create "observers", each tailored to listen for specific events. The observer would hear the messages reporting, say, Bluetooth state changes, and call a user-defined handler. It would be an AppleScript application that stays idle in the background. It's probably not a bad solution, but there are more ideal languages in which to implement this solution, say, as a background process or command line tool.

Comment: I get EventScripts to work like a charm ! Thanks @user3439894, worth every penny..!

Comment: Oooh, _EventScripts_.  Totally forgot about that app.  Nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, many thanks to CJK for the explanations!

After some struggle with [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) (because of how *Boom* is made, a Boom2device appears in the sound output devices and never really changes, so the trigger from Keyboard Maestro doesn't work...) I tried user3439894's solution and got [Eventscripts](https://www.mousedown.net/software/EventScripts.html) to work in less than 10 minutes!

The real plus with EventScripts is that you can choose which Bluetooth devices trigger the AppleScript.

Here's my set up:

[image]

With some scripts easy as:

- Quit Boom:

  ```
  quit application "Boom 2"
  ```

or

- Activate Boom:

  ```
  tell application "Finder"
      activate
      open application file "Boom 2.app" of folder "Applications" of startup disk
  end tell
  ```

I also made another one that came in my mind to adjust the brightness of the screen after plugging the MBP to the power with [brightness](https://github.com/nriley/brightness).

Comment: This is awesome.  I must definitely revisit EventScripts. If I recall, there's an accompanying iOS app too. +1